# How to receive a multipart message in ZMQ using Java?

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

As simple as this operation seems I can't find any documentation regarding how to receive a multipart message using ZMQ (Jeromq). I checked **The Guide** but it only contains C code with this info and it seems that I'm supposed to receive messages the same way no matter what kind of message I'm receiving.

In reality what happens is that I receive the multipart message in two messages with this code:

```java
while (running.get()) {
    items.poll();
    if (items.pollin(0)) {
        ByteArray message = receiver.recv(0);
        System.out.println("Received " + String(message, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    }
}
```

The "Received" part will get printed twice if I send a multipart message like this:

```java
publisher.sendMore(message.key);
publisher.send(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message.data));
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I know there is a language selector below the examples but this particular problem is not present in any of the examples only explained inline with `C` code.

**Edit**

I tried to explore the API and found the `hasReceiveMore()` method. I tried using it, but it didn't work, I ended up with an infinite loop with this code:

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
while(receiver.hasReceiveMore()) {
    parts.add(receiver.recvStr());
}
```

Comment: Beneath most snippets of C code in the guide is a language selector.  Just choose Java.

Comment: I added an edit to my question.

Comment: maybe recvPicture?

Comment: I checked this pictuer stuff, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to use it.

Comment: I'm guessing/hoping that just passing "m" will work.

Answer (score -1):

> **Q** : *"What am I doing wrong?"*

Your code has to actively assume each message to might have been composed as a multipart-message (Zero-Warranties in this, the less a-priori) and actively check for the presence of the **`ZMQ_RECVMORE`** flag, after each subsequent `.recv()`-method call, until the `.getsockopt( ZMQ_RECVMORE )`-method says otherwise.

JeroMQ might have translated this published native-API into some other utlity methods, so best re-read the JeroMQ-source code to find, where this native-API multipart-message handling-"protocol" gets wrapped into the JeroMQ-tooling.

> **EPILOGUE :** *Verba docent, Exempla trahunt...*
> Having helped more than 1.3 M Community members and countless anonymous site visitors, I got punished and censored for helping.
> <sub>Censorship of deleting comments continues. The spirit of StackOverflow turns to digital totalitarianism. Delete, delete and punish those, who keep thinking and present help and advice to those, who ask for a sponsored help...
> -------------------------------------
> Let's review the facts:
> -----
> ***"I couldn't find any docs regarding how I should receive the parts, but I tried something that looks like what you mentioned...it didn't work either.** – [Adam Arold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485337/adam-arold) [20 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189420/how-to-receive-a-multipart-message-in-zmq-using-java#comment113515097_64193580)"*
>
> Either of not finding "any docs" or a "not working" (another not published, reproducible MCVE) were my fault or omission, were they?
>
> *( my answer to these false claims was administratively deleted a few minutes after being posted... Self-explanatory )*
> -----
> ***"This is not an answer and it doesn't contain a solution. I'm not sure why you're surprised. What you cited is the C API that has nothing to do with the JeroMQ API. In the end the solution was that I have to `recv` before I try to check the `RECVMORE` flag. This was not in your answer. Alternatively `ZMsg` can be used.** – [Adam Arold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485337/adam-arold) [11 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189420/how-to-receive-a-multipart-message-in-zmq-using-java#comment113524503_64193580)"*
>
>
> **ANALYSIS OF THE CLAIMS :**
>
> Sentence #1. :
>
> ***"This is not an answer and it doesn't contain a solution."***
>
> This **IS** an answer, in spite of the "claim". It contains several important pieces of information, that she/he/anyone would otherwise have to try to seek for hours (days or weeks?) to later study and conceptually well comprehend architecture-wise so as not to make any ill-formulated code-design(s) or get principally trapped into one's own, misconcepted, decisions, if not having been advised and warned about thses possible shortcommings I've personally met ( and help others not to repeat ) throughout my last 13+ years spent with fabulous Martin Sustrik's masterpiece - the ZeroMQ, since v2.1+. So this "claim" is both wrong and unsupported by facts. A minor "claim" that the answer did not contain a solution is absurd, StackOverflow Community members are neither an employee to shout at, the less we bear a commitment to program a code that will snap and fit all the needs of the (unpublished) use-case.
>
> Sentence #2 :
>
> *(an expressed feeling)
> - rather skipped as it is more a case of insult than a fair argument, isn't it?*
>
> Sentence #3 :
>
> ***"What you cited is the C API that has nothing to do with the JeroMQ API."***
>
> Oh sure, **YES** , the C API ( and the ZeroMQ-RFC docs on mandatory "wire-line" protocols properties that any peer-implementation has to obey... ) is the starting point and a cardinal reference in all of this. And **NO** ,  both the published ZeroMQ RFC-documents and the API are the rock-solid reference for anyone to start with, so as to best understand, how the internal engines and all the mandatory "wire-line" properties obeying protocol pumps are working (and must be working), so as to declare themselves to retain the ZeroMQ-compatibility. The JeroMQ-authors did their work based on these documented properties, didn't they? If they did not or if they "cut some corners" on doing that, the story is lost and was not my fault they did not meet and/or cover all the ZMTP/ZeroMQ-RFC/API properties & requirements, was it? That said, any wrapper/binding, including any version of the JeroMQ must also conform to these inner working rules, which is sufficiently self-documented & demonstrated, if nowhere else, in the JeroMQ source-code (Which warning was also the part of the Answer provided, wasn't it?), if it aspires to be a ZeroMQ-compatible tool. Again, should your current (used) JeroMQ-implementation misses to meet a well documented JeroMQ-API documentation you would like to use & read through (to **find** both the description and **examples** of code for the use-cases), which was claimed it did not or that the will to seek and find any such (source-coded) information, it is not the Community sponsoring member to punish for the lack of both the former, the more the latter.
>
> Sentence 4. + 5. :
>
> This needs to get highlighted:
>
> ***"In the end the solution was that I have to `recv` before I try to check the `RECVMORE` flag. This was not in your answer."***
>
> First of all, it **WAS** in the Answer - the very first sentence:
> *"...code has to actively assume each message to might have been composed as a multipart-message (Zero-Warranties in this, the less a-priori) and actively check for the presence of the `ZMQ_RECVMORE` flag, **after** each subsequent `.recv()`-method call, until the `.getsockopt( ZMQ_RECVMORE )`-method says otherwise."*
>
>
> My generation grew up in a deep belief, that if we've made an error or 've made a poor decision, based on an unsupported assumption, we never punish anyone else, for (us) having made an error of a bad decision. **Surprisingly, not working here.** Why would anyone ever punish a person, who reached out and came to help you solve your problem and sponsored your personal need to get a step further? No one will if the culture to ask for a sponsored help and punish anyone who did would grow further. Isn't this called an arrogant or dictator-alike style of person to person behaviour? Be it the former or latter, it is neither fair, the less a style to be promoted the less rewarded as a Community preferred behaviour. The "argument" per se is empty, void - Not having called a `.recv()`-method, nothing gets ever from inside the ZeroMQ-API abstract horizon, the less an indication, promised to learn by `.getsockopt()`-method's use on getting a `RECVMORE`-flag ( sure, after some `.recv()` has been confirmed to have gotten a substance --The-Message-- That is both elementary and does not need to "include" it in any text about ZeroMQ/JeroMQ messaging as it is self-explanatory - Would anyone claim that it was unfair not to explain that asking for an email-attachment makes no sense if there were no email delivered so far? No one fair ever would. So, the Answer did the very opposite - it did warn about this, that for every `.recv()`-ed message, professional designer ought always assume a **`{ 0+ }`-`RECVMORE`-flagged** multi-part message components, that follow the first one `.recv()`-ed and need to get dug out of the API.
>
> The last sentence :
>
> ***"Alternatively `ZMsg` can be used."***
>
> This claim remains an undecidable problem, as the O/P contains zero information about a version. Native ZeroMQ API has evolved since its premiere release via v2.0-v2.1-..-v2.11, via v3.0-v3.1-v3.2, refactored and extended via v4.0-v4.1-v4.2-v4.3 and still counting, and a "claimed" `Zmsg`-abstraction is sure not to be present in earlier implementations, so the version number is cardinal on this ( also being a part of the StackOverflow best practices for how to ask good questions with a problem-reproducing MCVE / MWE code and all relevant details, the version number being one part of that, isn't it? ).</sub>

Comment: I couldn't find any docs regarding how I should receive the parts, but I tried something that looks like what you mentioned...it didn't work either.

Comment: This is not an answer and it doesn't contain a solution. I'm not sure why you're surprised. What you cited is the `C` API that has nothing to do with the JeroMQ API. In the end the solution was that I have to `recv` before I try to check the `RECVMORE` flag. This was not in your answer. Alternatively `ZMsg` can be used.